# Mirror command not works for folders with space

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I am trying to mirror a file which having space but not able to succeed.
Can some one give me a trigger

```
mirror %Viewdir%:\app_gw\Release Info c:\build\Release Info /R
```

"Release Info" is having space so not working

Comment: mirror "%Viewdir%:\app_gw\Release Info" "c:\build\Release Info" /R

This wil work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest surrounding your paths in quotation marks like so:

```
"%Viewdir%:\app_gw\Release Info"
```

And the same for what you are wanting to mirror to. This should work, at least it has for me.

I hope this helped :)